# Azure Dev Ops | Sprint Board | Load with tags applied by default

Tags: azure-devops

is it possible, to load an ADO Sprint Board with certain tags defaulted on by using a custom URL or coding?

For example, please see attached image.

Image of Tags exposed on an ADO Sprint Kanban Board

[image: 1]

Thank you for your help.

I tried finding articles related to creating a custom URL but did not have any luck specific to this use case.

I am hoping there is a way to provide this feature please let me know

Comment: hi sudeep, what is the latest status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

During my test, I checked the url and found if you are going to visit the page with the wits of specific tags. You could test the urls below.

**To Boards/Sprints**

[https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_sprints/taskboard/{TeamName}/{IterationName}?System.Tags={TagName}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borg%7D/%7Bproj%7D/_sprints/taskboard/%7BTeamName%7D/%7BIterationName%7D?System.Tags=%7BTagName%7D)

**To Boards/Boards**

[https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Proj}/_boards/board/t/{TeamName}/{Backlog_navigation_levels}?System.Tags={TagName}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrg%7D/%7BProj%7D/_boards/board/t/%7BTeamName%7D/%7BBacklog_navigation_levels%7D?System.Tags=%7BTagName%7D)